# Why implicit type inference only works in an assignment?

Tags: java, generics

I know that using generic in an assignment, a method can implicitly know the type of the return type by looking at the type of the left hand side variable.

Example from Google Collection:

```
List<String> l = Lists.newArrayList()
```

My question is why it doesn't work for a method or higher type of inference?

Example:

```
List<List<String>> ll = Lists.newArrayList();
ll.put(Lists.newArrayList()); // doesn't work
```

Is this specified in the JLS? If yes, why? If no, then is this a kind of improvement that I can expect from Java 7?

This annoyed me because seems that we have a problem in Java like I have problem in Delphi a long time ago where I can't do chained method call like:

```
C c = a.b().c();
```

In Delphi (IIRC), you have to do:

```
B b = a.b();
C c = b.c();
```

Looks like a 'dejavu'

Comment: You could probably do `C c = ((B) a.b()).c()` instead of `C c = a.b().c();`

Comment: No you can't... like I say... You can't do method chaining at all in Delphi (along time ago, don't know the current state of Delphi).

Comment: Is this question appropriate for StackOverflow?  It seems subjective, and allows only for speculative answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't like to claim particular knowledge here, but there's one obvious difference between assignment to a variable, and using the value as a method argument: there's only one *possible* target in the former case, whether the method is overloaded or not.

Basically it means that you don't need to worry about type inference and overloading / conversions interacting: the inference *only* happens in the case where you know the one and only target type you're interested in.

This *is* just a guess though. I've always found Java's type inference interesting - it works the exact opposite way to C# 3, where you can infer the *variable's* type (so long as it's a local variable).

EDIT: I believe the relevant [JLS section is 15.12.2.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.8):

> If the method result occurs in a
>   context where it will be subject to
>   assignment conversion (§5.2) to a type
>   S, then let R be the declared result
>   type of the method [...]

Basically it's the "assignment conversion" bit which is important.

Comment: In case of method overloading, I agree with you that we have to explicitly specify the type. Heck... in Java you can even create one method with particular parameter R and another method that with parameter sub R and it works, so I don't believe the 'confusion' is the problem here.

Comment: your edit solve the question whether the JLS mentioned it, thank you. Now have you any idea 'why' such inference limited only to an assignment?

Comment: @nanda: The first two paragraphs are my guess at the "why" - it keeps the language simpler. Mixing type inference and overloading would be painful. Admittedly the common case would only have a single choice, but special-casing that would be painful too. (C# has a similar issue for type inference when passing method groups to a method taking a delegate, btw.)